# Git bundle on standard output

Tags: git, bundle

I want to generate a bundle with git but for some important reason I need it on the standard output not in a file.
Is there a alternate command at `git bundle` to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-` as the *file* argument to `git bundle`:

```
$ git bundle create - HEAD~10.. > outfile    
Counting objects: 83, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (67/67), done.
Writing objects: 100% (68/68), 8.42 KiB, done.
Total 68 (delta 55), reused 0 (delta 0)
$ file outfile
outfile: Git bundle
$ ls -l outfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 author author 8789 2012-09-21 15:20 outfile
```

**Note:** as of git 2.17.0, the above commands works correctly only when invoked at the root directory of the working tree. (In other directories, a `-` file is created and `outfile` ends up empty.)

Comment: On my git version 1.7.10.1 "git bundle create -" create a file called "-" but nothing on standard output. What version are you using ?

Comment: `git version 1.7.4.1`. The above output is actual paste from the terminal, with my just username changed to "author".

Comment: The same also works with `git version 1.7.12`. How exactly are you running it?

Comment: Yes, you're right it's work but not on the first computer I tested it (Fedora 17 with git 1.7.10.1). Thank you !!

Comment: This works when executed in the root dir of git repo, but not when executed in a sub dir. Tested on git 2.17.0. Do you think this is a bug?

Comment: @Cyker Yes, I can confirm that `git bundle create - ...`, when executed in a directory other than the root dir, produces a file named `-` (and the standard output ends up empty). It definitely looks like a bug.